# How to view what a user has access to with PowerShell?

Tags: permissions, powershell

A user has limited access but I don't know what for. How can I view what this user has access to?
 I'm on WSS 3.

Does anyone know of a PowerShell script to perform this method?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the permissions necessary to install solutions in your environment, I recommend checking out the Access Checker web part on CodePlex (http://accesschecker.codeplex.com).

When I check a "Limited Access" user's permissions with this web part, I see exactly what the user has access to in that site.  This solution only goes down to the list level, so if your site is using permissions at the folder or item level this won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

The [Sharepoint Admin Toolkit](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2009/08/27/3277616.aspx) provides some tools to help isolate some permissions issues.  Lightning Tools also has a product called [DeliverPoint](http://www.lightningtools.com/deliverpoint/sharepoint-permission-management.aspx) to help with permissions analysis.  I would be interested to see if/what the Powershell way would be.  In WSS3, the options might be a bit limited.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a detailed report on SharePoint users access on various elements of SharePoint platform, including Web Application/Site Collection/Site/List level with the help of PowerShell.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/01/permission-report-for-specific-user.html

Comment: Please provide more information! If the link breaks, this answer will be useless to future readers